# Postfix send mail as other user

Tags: postfix

i need to set well my Postfix server.
I realized that it is possible to send mails by changing the sender label in my client.
Mail was arrived with other sender!!!

how can I configure it to avoid this sending with the name of another?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The [`smtpd_sender_restrictions`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions) has `reject_sender_login_mismatch`:

> - **`reject_sender_login_mismatch`**
>
>   As of Postfix 2.1, this is an alias for "`reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch`, `reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch`".
> - **`reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch`**
>
>   Reject the request when the client is authenticated with SASL, but either the MAIL FROM address is not listed in [`$smtpd_sender_login_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps), or the SASL login name is not an owner for that address.
>
>   This prevents an authenticated client from using a MAIL FROM address that they do not explicitly own. This feature is available in Postfix version 2.1 and later.
> - **`reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch`**
>
>   Reject the request when SASL is enabled, the MAIL FROM address is listed in [`$smtpd_sender_login_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps), but the client is not authenticated with SASL.
>
>   With SASL enabled, this prevents an unauthenticated client from using any MAIL FROM address that is listed in [`$smtpd_sender_login_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps).
>   This feature is available in Postfix version 2.1 and later.

If you are using [`virtual_alias_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps) to deliver the mail, the [`smtpd_sender_login_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps) has the same format; the same file can be used for both, updating the allowed addresses at the same time you add addresses for delivery.

Say you are using SMTPS on port `465` for submission, you can add these directives under it in `master.cf`:

```
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
```

The `/etc/postfix/virtual` has the addresses with the corresponding users:

```
# address                username
joe.bloggs@example.com   joe
jane.smith@example.com   jane
```

As it is a [`hash:` Berkeley DB](https://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types), remember `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` after modifications.

Comment: This all is true, but you only could lock *envelope from* address like this. The "from" address that you see in the mail user agent comes from the email MIME header, and it needs not to be the same as envelope address, so it still could be faked. (I am sure you know, but whoever asked this question or found it may not know this detail yet.)

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov: That's true, but this is practically quite effective for two reasons. 1) The scenario was users changing the sender address on their email client. Typically the clients won't allow configuring envelope sender separately. 2) While an advanced user could abuse this, the actual sender would still be visible as the envelope sender (`Return-Path`).

Comment: Thanks. i will try it as soon as possible